# personalised QR for app installation

Tags: installation, store, qr-code

I need to create QR code for installing/downloading my mobile application from Android/Apple store.

Is it possible to create QR code including both link to my application in store and some data which will used automatically in installation process of my application. In other words, I would like to create personalised QR code for application installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can convert the what you need into a URL (with GET parameters probably), you can then use any QR generating app to convert that URL into a QR

Comment: I understand, but how my mobile application can use the parameters from URL when users download this application from store?